# overlay two plots with different x scale

Tags: r

I would like to overlay two plots:

plot1

```
t1 <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
d1 <- c(0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20)
```

plot2

```
t2 <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5)    
d2 <- c(1,3,7,8,8,8)
```

I tried

```
plot(d1~t1, col="black", type="l")
par(new=T)
plot(d2~t2, col="black", type="l")
```

But the problem is: in this way, both x axes also overlay each other while x in plot1 is 1:10 and plot2 1:5

Comment: Are you just looking for `plot(d1 ~ t1, type = "l") ; lines(t2, d2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `lines` for the second plot (instead of `plot`). Furthermore, we scale the x-axis values of the second plot (`t2`) with 2 (`I(2 * t2)`).

```
plot(d1 ~ t1, col="black", type="l", xlim=c(0,10))
lines(d2 ~ I(2 * t2), col="black", type="l", xlim=c(0,5))
```

In this way, the x-range of the second plot is identical to the x-range of the first one.

[image]